# 2010 Document Center

Tags: permissions, document, library, access, denied

SharePoint 2010 - I have a user who is able to upload a document to the document center, but when she attempts to access the document she get 'Access Denied'.

There is a workflow that sets permission groups to full control via Impersonation step.

She is a member of 3 of the groups. I additionally granted her Contribute access individually to the library.  She can go there directly using library URL, but coming from a link she get 'Access Denied'.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the full URL. The URL she is getting is the url of the library or the document. If it is document, probably document is having unique permission and thats why she is getting access denied. Try to check the permission of the document.